# mutate a new column that is the row sum of numeric features?

Tags: r

I have a data frame with some trended data but the dates are columnwise / wide. Here's the head:

```
structure(list(Medium = c("(none)", "(not set)", "20190723-Sales-Tax-notification", 
"20190729-Notification", "20190820_All_Others_Europe_Deprecation", 
"20190820_PBX_Accounts_co-branded_Deprecation"), `01-Jan` = c(7443, 
26, 3, 1, 1, 2), `02-Jan` = c(10283, 57, 6, 4, 3, 1), `03-Jan` = c(9753, 
53, 15, 2, 1, 4), `04-Jan` = c(8129, 18, 7, 0, 4, 2), `05-Jan` = c(9209, 
28, 5, 0, 2, 8), `06-Jan` = c(11617, 37, 21, 4, 3, 3), `07-Jan` = c(11768, 
20, 8, 3, 0, 3), `08-Jan` = c(11267, 38, 12, 4, 0, 5), `09-Jan` = c(10790, 
40, 10, 2, 2, 3), `10-Jan` = c(9733, 27, 5, 0, 0, 1), `11-Jan` = c(7372, 
22, 8, 1, 5, 4), `12-Jan` = c(9119, 31, 4, 1, 2, 4), `13-Jan` = c(11642, 
36, 12, 1, 4, 2), `14-Jan` = c(11226, 56, 8, 0, 4, 1), `15-Jan` = c(10841, 
50, 5, 0, 6, 1), `16-Jan` = c(10471, 40, 9, 1, 2, 2), `17-Jan` = c(9774, 
53, 9, 4, 0, 2), `18-Jan` = c(7655, 36, 9, 1, 3, 4), `19-Jan` = c(8341, 
32, 10, 0, 3, 4), `20-Jan` = c(11191, 57, 10, 1, 2, 4), `21-Jan` = c(11284, 
37, 13, 3, 0, 0), `22-Jan` = c(10810, 34, 16, 0, 3, 2), `23-Jan` = c(10162, 
51, 10, 2, 1, 2), `24-Jan` = c(9570, 31, 0, 1, 0, 2), `25-Jan` = c(7409, 
25, 1, 1, 0, 2), `26-Jan` = c(8286, 39, 1, 0, 2, 3), `27-Jan` = c(12750, 
42, 0, 0, 1, 3), `28-Jan` = c(11308, 46, 1, 1, 3, 1), `29-Jan` = c(11189, 
36, 2, 0, 1, 1), `30-Jan` = c(10472, 42, 0, 1, 1, 3), `31-Jan` = c(10107, 
31, 0, 1, 0, 2), `01-Feb` = c(8392, 32, 0, 0, 4, 4), `02-Feb` = c(7940, 
41, 0, 0, 2, 11), `03-Feb` = c(11766, 55, 0, 2, 4, 11), `04-Feb` = c(11601, 
49, 0, 4, 3, 2), `05-Feb` = c(11212, 74, 0, 3, 2, 1), `06-Feb` = c(10868, 
58, 0, 0, 1, 3), `07-Feb` = c(9602, 55, 1, 1, 0, 3), `08-Feb` = c(7685, 
48, 0, 2, 0, 3), `09-Feb` = c(8842, 59, 0, 3, 3, 6), `10-Feb` = c(12087, 
60, 1, 2, 3, 8), `11-Feb` = c(11484, 56, 3, 1, 6, 10), `12-Feb` = c(11050, 
59, 0, 0, 3, 9), `13-Feb` = c(10905, 56, 1, 0, 2, 3), `14-Feb` = c(9245, 
40, 0, 0, 2, 3), `15-Feb` = c(7446, 38, 1, 0, 0, 2), `16-Feb` = c(8348, 
40, 3, 0, 4, 2), `17-Feb` = c(10961, 66, 0, 1, 2, 1), `18-Feb` = c(11349, 
56, 2, 0, 2, 3), `19-Feb` = c(10829, 37, 0, 0, 0, 1), `20-Feb` = c(10611, 
44, 0, 0, 0, 0), `21-Feb` = c(9372, 40, 0, 1, 0, 0), `22-Feb` = c(7597, 
46, 0, 0, 0, 0), `23-Feb` = c(8514, 68, 0, 0, 0, 0), `24-Feb` = c(11553, 
68, 0, 0, 0, 0), `25-Feb` = c(11309, 56, 0, 0, 0, 0), `26-Feb` = c(10958, 
75, 0, 0, 0, 0), `27-Feb` = c(10703, 52, 0, 0, 0, 0), `28-Feb` = c(9544, 
43, 0, 0, 0, 0), `29-Feb` = c(7723, 16, 2, 0, 0, 0), `01-Mar` = c(8985, 
27, 0, 0, 0, 0), `02-Mar` = c(12130, 37, 0, 0, 0, 0), `03-Mar` = c(11235, 
34, 1, 0, 0, 0), `04-Mar` = c(10930, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0), `05-Mar` = c(10454, 
17, 0, 0, 0, 0), `06-Mar` = c(9206, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0), `07-Mar` = c(7301, 
16, 0, 0, 0, 0), `08-Mar` = c(7852, 28, 1, 1, 0, 0), `09-Mar` = c(11011, 
29, 2, 1, 0, 0), `10-Mar` = c(11309, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0), `11-Mar` = c(10426, 
13, 0, 1, 0, 0), `12-Mar` = c(9326, 28, 0, 0, 0, 0), `13-Mar` = c(8244, 
18, 0, 0, 0, 1), `14-Mar` = c(6888, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0), `15-Mar` = c(7691, 
12, 2, 0, 0, 0), `16-Mar` = c(9227, 15, 0, 0, 0, 0), `17-Mar` = c(9133, 
15, 1, 0, 0, 0), `18-Mar` = c(8868, 18, 0, 0, 0, 0), `19-Mar` = c(8632, 
14, 0, 1, 0, 0), `20-Mar` = c(7999, 16, 1, 0, 0, 0), `21-Mar` = c(6796, 
8, 0, 0, 0, 1), `22-Mar` = c(6729, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0), `23-Mar` = c(8897, 
10, 0, 0, 0, 0), `24-Mar` = c(8755, 13, 0, 0, 0, 0), `25-Mar` = c(8947, 
5, 0, 0, 0, 0), `26-Mar` = c(8229, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0), `27-Mar` = c(7951, 
12, 1, 0, 0, 0), `28-Mar` = c(6926, 10, 0, 0, 0, 0), `29-Mar` = c(7112, 
5, 2, 0, 0, 0), `01-Apr` = c(8282, 8, 0, 0, 0, 0), `02-Apr` = c(8041, 
16, 0, 0, 0, 0), `03-Apr` = c(7728, 9, 0, 0, 0, 0), `04-Apr` = c(6307, 
7, 1, 0, 0, 0), `05-Apr` = c(6341, 7, 1, 0, 0, 0), `06-Apr` = c(8241, 
7, 0, 0, 0, 0), `07-Apr` = c(7575, 11, 0, 0, 0, 0), `08-Apr` = c(7719, 
3, 0, 0, 0, 0), `09-Apr` = c(7707, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0), `10-Apr` = c(7487, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0), `11-Apr` = c(6159, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Looks like this:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 101
  Medium `01-Jan` `02-Jan` `03-Jan` `04-Jan` `05-Jan` `06-Jan` `07-Jan` `08-Jan` `09-Jan` `10-Jan` `11-Jan`
  <chr>     <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
1 (none)     7443    10283     9753     8129     9209    11617    11768    11267    10790     9733     7372
2 (not …       26       57       53       18       28       37       20       38       40       27       22
3 20190…        3        6       15        7        5       21        8       12       10        5        8
4 20190…        1        4        2        0        0        4        3        4        2        0        1
5 20190…        1        3        1        4        2        3        0        0        2        0        5
6 20190…        2        1        4        2        8        3        3        5        3        1        4
```

So, for each date and feature 'medium' is a value, sessions. I would like to insert a column between medium and what is current 1st January, i.e. insert a new second column after Medium which contains the sum total of all the remaining numeric fields on that row. I looked at rowSums but could not see how to use it in this context.

How can I add a new column that contains the total sessions for each medium?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To insert to a specific position, we can use `add_column`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tibble)
df1 %>% 
     add_column(Sum = rowSums(.[-1], na.rm = TRUE), .after = 'Medium')
# A tibble: 6 x 102
#  Medium    Sum `01-Jan` `02-Jan` `03-Jan` `04-Jan` `05-Jan` `06-Jan` `07-Jan` `08-Jan` `09-Jan` `10-Jan` `11-Jan` `12-Jan` `13-Jan`
#  <chr>   <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl>
#1 (none) 939243     7443    10283     9753     8129     9209    11617    11768    11267    10790     9733     7372     9119    11642
#2 (not …   3196       26       57       53       18       28       37       20       38       40       27       22       31       36
#3 20190…    247        3        6       15        7        5       21        8       12       10        5        8        4       12
#4 20190…     64        1        4        2        0        0        4        3        4        2        0        1        1        1
#5 20190…    102        1        3        1        4        2        3        0        0        2        0        5        2        4
#6 20190…    169        2        1        4        2        8        3        3        5        3        1        4        4        2
# … with 87 more variables: `14-Jan` <dbl>, `15-Jan` <dbl>, `16-Jan` <dbl>, `17-Jan` <dbl>, `18-Jan` <dbl>, `19-Jan` <dbl>,
#   `20-Jan` <dbl>, `21-Jan` <dbl>, `22-Jan` <dbl>, `23-Jan` <dbl>, `24-Jan` <dbl>, `25-Jan` <dbl>, `26-Jan` <dbl>, `27-Jan` <dbl>,
#   `28-Jan` <dbl>, `29-Jan` <dbl>, `30-Jan` <dbl>, `31-Jan` <dbl>, `01-Feb` <dbl>, `02-Feb` <dbl>, `03-Feb` <dbl>, `04-Feb` <dbl>,
#   `05-Feb` <dbl>, `06-Feb` <dbl>, `07-Feb` <dbl>, `08-Feb` <dbl>, `09-Feb` <dbl>, `10-Feb` <dbl>, `11-Feb` <dbl>, `12-Feb` <dbl>,
#   `13-Feb` <dbl>, `14-Feb` <dbl>, `15-Feb` <dbl>, `16-Feb` <dbl>, `17-Feb` <dbl>, `18-Feb` <dbl>, `19-Feb` <dbl>, `20-Feb` <dbl>,
#   `21-Feb` <dbl>, `22-Feb` <dbl>, `23-Feb` <dbl>, `24-Feb` <dbl>, `25-Feb` <dbl>, `26-Feb` <dbl>, `27-Feb` <dbl>, `28-Feb` <dbl>,
#   `29-Feb` <dbl>, `01-Mar` <dbl>, `02-Mar` <dbl>, `03-Mar` <dbl>, `04-Mar` <dbl>, `05-Mar` <dbl>, `06-Mar` <dbl>, `07-Mar` <dbl>,
#   `08-Mar` <dbl>, `09-Mar` <dbl>, `10-Mar` <dbl>, `11-Mar` <dbl>, `12-Mar` <dbl>, `13-Mar` <dbl>, `14-Mar` <dbl>, `15-Mar` <dbl>,
#   `16-Mar` <dbl>, `17-Mar` <dbl>, `18-Mar` <dbl>, `19-Mar` <dbl>, `20-Mar` <dbl>, `21-Mar` <dbl>, `22-Mar` <dbl>, `23-Mar` <dbl>,
#   `24-Mar` <dbl>, `25-Mar` <dbl>, `26-Mar` <dbl>, `27-Mar` <dbl>, `28-Mar` <dbl>, `29-Mar` <dbl>, `01-Apr` <dbl>, `02-Apr` <dbl>,
#   `03-Apr` <dbl>, `04-Apr` <dbl>, `05-Apr` <dbl>, `06-Apr` <dbl>, `07-Apr` <dbl>, `08-Apr` <dbl>, `09-Apr` <dbl>, `10-Apr` <dbl>,
#   `11-Apr` <dbl>
```

---

Or another approach is with `select_if` with `numeric` variables, do the `+` with `reduce` and later rearrange the column positions in `select`

```
library(purrr)
df1 %>%
     mutate(Sum = select_if(., is.numeric) %>% 
                     reduce(`+`)) %>%
     select(Medium, Sum, everything())
```

NOTE: `rowSums` is more robust as it can deal with missing values with `na.rm` or we can also use `pmap`

```
df1 %>%
     mutate(Sum = select_if(., is.numeric) %>% 
                     pmap_dbl(sum, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
     select(Medium, Sum, everything())
```

---

Or using `base R`

```
df1 <-  cbind(df1[1], Sum = rowSums(df1[-1], na.rm = TRUE), df1[-1])
```

Comment: This is great, thanks a lot. I went with `add_column()` because I personally found it the most readable and intuitive.